# If a cell's detailTextLabel is empty how do I figure out where its right edge would be if it wasn't empty?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a table view for a form. When a row is tapped I add a text field to the cell (the cell is a value1 type) and the user can edit the contents of detailTextLabel. I position the text field so that it spans the distance from the right edge of textLabel to the right edge of detailTextLabel. Basically I set the frame of the text field over detailTextLabel except that it goes to the left as far as possible. Visually it's nice--there are no jitters when hiding/unhiding the text field.

It looks like this (without the green and red):

[image]

This works great when detailTextLabel has something in it. But when detailTextLabel is empty its frame is not yet defined. If you log it everything in frame is zero. So then I don't have a reference for placing the text field precisely over where detailTextLabel would be.

I could start figuring things out from the right side of textLabel and just go to the right until some number of pixels from the right edge of the cell. But, for example, what if there's an info button there? The nice thing about using detailTextLabel as a reference is that it's right edge is already correctly placed for that cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can always put a space (' ') instead of empty label. This way it will not be visible to the user, and you still get nice reference.

Comment: @sha That's a great idea. And I don't even need to deal with the space later because when I display the text field I get its value from the model, not detailTextLabel. If you move your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I will post it as an answer - so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always put a space (' ') instead of empty label. This way it will not be visible to the user, and you still get nice reference